# Construction of selection index using specific combination of covariance

Tags: r, combinations

I am new in R coding. I have matrix data from which I want to construct selection index related to my research area. I need to select all combinations of matrix from the given matrix to construct the index. I have 4x4 matrix data, so I will get 11 combination. I can do it, but it is too long. For example,

```
P<- matrix(c (
6.63561, 0.13564, 5.15061, 5.97293,
0.13564, 0.39768, 2.42954, 1.76955,
5.15061, 2.42954, 62.6952, 36.5748,
5.97293, 1.76955, 36.5748, 29.0475
), c( 4,4))


 G <-matrix(c(
 6.25705, 0.12236, 5.13621, 5.95043,
 0.12236, 0.23997, 2.06681, 1.45389,
 5.13621, 2.06681, 59.1681, 33.5396,
 5.95043, 1.45389, 33.5396, 26.168
 ), c(4,4))

A<-c(1,1,1,1)

B<- (solve(P)%*%G)%*%A
B<-abs(B)

g12 <- G[c( 1 , 2 ) , c( 1 , 2 )]              
g124 <- G[c( 1 , 2 , 4 ) , c( 1 , 2 , 4 )]          
g1234 <- G[c( 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 ) , c( 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 )] 

a12 <- A[c( 1 , 2 )]              
a124 <- A[c( 1 , 2 , 4 )]          
a1234 <- A[c( 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 )]  

b12 <- B[c( 1 , 2 )]              
b124 <- B[c( 1 , 2 , 4 )]          
b1234 <- B[c( 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 )]      


result<-c(w12 <-sum( g12 %*% b12 * a12 ),
w124 <-sum( g124 %*% b124 * a124 ),
w1234 <-sum( g1234 %*% b1234 * a1234 ))
```

Here, I showed three combination. Result is here

```
  > result
 [1]   7.438186  39.689388 180.665871
```

But I need all 11 combination. When I use 6x6 matrix I have to make 57 combination manually which is tiresome. So I am searching short language. Actually, I want the result like the following table, where, comb.= combination, Var_comb=variable combination(4 variables), index= analyzed value.

```
> SEL_INDEX
   comb.   Var_comb  index

1     12      x1x2  7.43  
2     13      x1x3  83,27 
3     14      x1x4  37.43 
4     23      x2x3  68.33 
5     24      x2x4  21.27 
6     34      x3x4  145.31 
7    123    x1x2x3  87.07 
8    124    x1x2x4  39.69 
9    134    x1x3x4  174.96 
10   234    x2x3x4  150.81 
11  1234  x1x2x3x4  180.66
```

I will be grateful if anyone helps me to do this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a straight forward approach in base R:

```
index <- do.call(c, lapply(2:4, function(x) {
    combn(4, x, function(y) {
        sum(G[y,y] %*% B[y] * A[y])
    })
}))

index
[1]   7.438186  83.270451  37.435149  68.331049  21.273907 145.311921
[7]  87.071171  39.689388 174.958491 150.810089 180.665871
```

### Edit:

And here is how you would produce the requested table.:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(2:4, function(x) {
    do.call(rbind, combn(4, x, function(y) {
        data.frame(comb. = paste(y, collapse = ""),
                   Var_comb = paste(c("", y), collapse = "x"),
                   index = sum(G[y,y] %*% B[y] * A[y]),
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    }, simplify = FALSE))
}))

   comb. Var_comb      index
1     12     x1x2   7.438186
2     13     x1x3  83.270451
3     14     x1x4  37.435149
4     23     x2x3  68.331049
5     24     x2x4  21.273907
6     34     x3x4 145.311921
7    123   x1x2x3  87.071171
8    124   x1x2x4  39.689388
9    134   x1x3x4 174.958491
10   234   x2x3x4 150.810089
11  1234 x1x2x3x4 180.665871
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response @ Joseph Wood . You have made my task easier than ever.

Comment: @Rokib, no problem... last night as I was answering, I forgot to add how you can easily produce a data.frame with a very similar setup.

Comment: Excellent. I can't resist myself to say thanks again @Joseph Wood.